# Get data from cloned element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem. In my form a I have div

```
<div class="wyksztalcenie">
<select id="szkola">
    <option value="Wyższe">Wyższe</option>
    <option value="Średnie">Średnie</option>
    <option value="Zawodowe">Zawodowe</option>
</select> 
<input class="cos1" id="nazwa" name="nazwaszkoly" placeholder="nazwa uczelni/szkoły" type="text" /> 
<input class="cos1" id="kierunek" name="kier" placeholder="kierunek" type="text" /> 
<input class="cos1" id="rok" name="rok" placeholder="rok ukończenia" type="text" />
</div>
```

I've cloned this div five times and my problem is to get data from input and select in cloned div. In this user choose level of education (high school, college, etc.) and then I send it to database in format "Select-input-input-input". This is ok but only the first div is save into database.
Can anyone help me

Comment: And what have you tried for this?

Comment: Without knowing what you've tried we don't know what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: change the `id` to `class` because same ids for multiple elems are invalid markup and if this happens brower takes the first one which occurs in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simulate your problem;

**HTML**(I assume, you have already cloned it):

```
<div class="wyksztalcenie">
<select class="szkola">
    <option value="Wyższe">Wyższe</option>
    <option value="Średnie">Średnie</option>
    <option value="Zawodowe">Zawodowe</option>
</select> 
<input class="cos1" id="nazwa" name="nazwaszkoly" placeholder="nazwa uczelni/szkoły" type="text" /> 
<input class="cos1" id="kierunek" name="kier" placeholder="kierunek" type="text" /> 
<input class="cos1" id="rok" name="rok" placeholder="rok ukończenia" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="wyksztalcenie">
<select class="szkola">
    <option value="Wyższe">Wyższe</option>
    <option value="Średnie">Średnie</option>
    <option value="Zawodowe">Zawodowe</option>
</select> 
<input class="cos1" id="nazwa" name="nazwaszkoly" placeholder="nazwa uczelni/szkoły" type="text" /> 
<input class="cos1" id="kierunek" name="kier" placeholder="kierunek" type="text" /> 
<input class="cos1" id="rok" name="rok" placeholder="rok ukończenia" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="wyksztalcenie">
<select class="szkola">
    <option value="Wyższe">Wyższe</option>
    <option value="Średnie">Średnie</option>
    <option value="Zawodowe">Zawodowe</option>
</select> 
<input class="cos1" id="nazwa" name="nazwaszkoly" placeholder="nazwa uczelni/szkoły" type="text" /> 
<input class="cos1" id="kierunek" name="kier" placeholder="kierunek" type="text" /> 
<input class="cos1" id="rok" name="rok" placeholder="rok ukończenia" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="wyksztalcenie">
<select class="szkola">
    <option value="Wyższe">Wyższe</option>
    <option value="Średnie">Średnie</option>
    <option value="Zawodowe">Zawodowe</option>
</select> 
<input class="cos1" id="nazwa" name="nazwaszkoly" placeholder="nazwa uczelni/szkoły" type="text" /> 
<input class="cos1" id="kierunek" name="kier" placeholder="kierunek" type="text" /> 
<input class="cos1" id="rok" name="rok" placeholder="rok ukończenia" type="text" />
</div>

<input type="button" id="send" value="Send"/>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#send").on("click", function() {
    var html ="";
    var counter = 1;
    $('.wyksztalcenie').each(function() {
        var selectValue = $(this).find('select').val();

        var inputOne = $(this).find('#nazwa').val();
        var inputTwo = $(this).find('#kierunek').val();
        var inputThree = $(this).find('#rok').val();

        html += "select-" + counter + "=" + selectValue + "&input-" + counter + "=" + inputOne + "&input-" + counter + "=" + inputTwo + "&input-" + counter + "=" + inputThree;
        html += "&";
        counter++;
    });
    html = html.substring(0, html.length-1);

    // Send data here
});
```

You can see working demo here: **http://jsfiddle.net/4egzF/**

**Note:** Update selectbox id to class. Id must be unique

Comment: @Tomek, if it solved your problem, upvote and apply my answer will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming five identical copies of the code above, something like this should work, where you reference each instance of `.wyksztalcenie` by index:

```
// selects the first (index zero) instance of the cloned div
// substitute 1-4 for the zero to get the others
//
$('.wyksztalcenie').eq(0).find('select').val();
```

If you want to loop through them all, use `each()`:

```
$('.wyksztalcenie').each(function() {
    var myVal = $(this).find('select').val();
    // do something with myVal
});
```

Comment: what if i want the value of fifth cloned div?

Comment: See the comments I added.

Comment: there are same ids which are gettting repeated which is an invalid markup and if this happens brower takes the first one which occurs in the page.

Comment: `value()` is not a jQuery method.

Comment: @Jai, true. Not really my concern here.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `name` attribute to the `select` element, and replace all `id` attributes with `class`.
Then all name attributes should have `[]` appended to them (example: `kier[]`).

Then you can find all five of them in an array on your processing page.